# d3.line chart with gaps (without gap data)

Tags: d3.js

I am facing  a problem about my d3.line chart (with gaps).

Take  a look on a piece of my object:

```
Populate MAX: 4.667 NAME: "p21" START: 14172
Populate MAX: 8.833 NAME: "p21" START: 14173
Populate MAX: 0.833 NAME: "p21" START: 17078
Populate MAX: 0.5 NAME: "p21" START: 17079
```

As one can see, I use START to define my x position, and MAX to define my line chart.

BUT, in this example, I do have a gap between element 1 and 2 (counting starts on 0).

it jumps from 14173(MAX 8.833) to 17078(MAX 0.833) and my chart "interpolates" all the gap between this positions.

I really don't know how to use .define in this case, given that I don't have all the missing data (gap data).

I could create this missing data and fill the gap, but I would have too many unused objects in my visualization.

Any insights ?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do. Do you want to have a gap in the line where data is missing?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff yes, where there are no data, there shouldn't be a line chart (I don't want d3.line) to interpolate 14173 to 17078. Given that, I also don't want to create "fake" position between the gap 'cause it would be huge. Right now I am "hacking" my db and adding 2 "fake" positions to each gap (example: 14173+1 and 17078-1 - with that d3 interpolates from 0 to 0. But it is really NOT a good solution. Any insights ?

Comment: You would have to create separate line segments manually. D3 doesn't really have a concept of "gap" with lines and linear scales, so you have to make it explicit (e.g. by having an array of array of points).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Path transition with gap - how do to that?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791251/path-transition-with-gap-how-do-to-that)