# Drawing different colored "strokes" between center and different nodes in a D3.js tree

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, colors

Here is my code. I am trying to connect/draw a path between center and different nodes. Now I want to make a different colored `stroke` for a different path. I have created an array of color that for which path what will be stroke color. But I can't make the `stroke` in a different color.

```
var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
                     .x(function(d) { return d.x;})
                     .y(function(d) { return d.y;})
                     .interpolate("linear");
var lineGraph = vis.append("g")
                  .append("path")
                  .attr("d", lineFunction(CenterList))
                  .attr("stroke", function(d, i) { return ColorArr[i]; } )
                  .attr("stroke-width", 5)
                  .attr("fill", "none")
                  .attr("id", "viz");

ColorArr=black, black, red, red, black, black, black, red, black, red;
```

Comment: The "lines" created by the line function are actually just a single SVG `<path>` element, which can only have a single stroke colour.  If you want each section of the line to have a different colour, then you need to make them each separate SVG `<line>` elements.

Comment: Ok @AmeliaBR Thanks a lot for clearing the concept , I am also guessing the same. Can you outline the changes I supposed to made to the code.

Comment: @Dibyendu Dutta, now you see how important is to write very clear questions: Amelia an I interpreted it in very different ways....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To style different line segments differently, they have to be separate line elements instead of all part of one path.

However, drawing a line graph as a series of line elements complicates the code.  For every point, you not only need to know the data at that point, you also need to the data for the previous or next point (the start or end of the line).

I had written up a (more complicated) example of making a line graph this way [for a previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20939701/3128209), so I was able to quickly adapt it for you.

Here's the fiddle:  http://fiddle.jshell.net/4xZwb/3/

For that example, I used an "each" call to group all the calculations:

```
var lines = svg.append("g").attr("class", "plot").selectAll("line");
        //define a d3 selection consisting of <line> elements
        //that are grouped within g.plot

    lines = lines.data(data);  
        //tell the selection to make room for every point in the data array

    lines.enter().append("line");
        //add one <line> element for every data point

    lines.each(function(d,i){
        //for each line in the selection, this function will be called
        //with d equal to the data point and i equal to the index
        //and "this" equal to the <line> element

        var value = d;
        //y-value for current point 
        //(we're just using the raw number from the array,
        //normally it would be something like d.y or d[1] )

        //find next point
        var next = i+1; //x-position (just using index #)
        var nextValue = data[i+1]; //y-position

        if (isNaN(nextValue)){
            // there is no next value,
            // so repeat this point as the end of line
            //(line will have zero length, but the marker will show up)
            next = i;
            nextValue = value;
        }

        d3.select(this) //select this particular <line> element
                        //so that we can use d3 methods

            //set coordinates:
            .attr( 
                {x1: xScale(i),
                 y1: yScale(value),
                 x2: xScale(next),
                 y2: yScale(nextValue)}
                )

            //Set styles for this individual line segment
            //e.g., based on whether value is increasing
            //or decreasing, we can set stroke colour red or black
            .style("stroke", ( (value > nextValue) ?
                              "red" :
                              "black" )
                  );
    });//end of "each" call
```

However, you could also set them individually, like in this version:

```
lines = lines.data(data);

lines.enter().append("line");

lines.attr("x1", function(d,i){return xScale(i);})
.attr("x2", function(d,i){
    return xScale( (i+1 == data.length)?i:i+1);
})
.attr("y1", function(d,i){return yScale(d);})
.attr("y2", function(d,i){
    return yScale( (i+1 == data.length)?
                  d:data[i+1]);
})
.style("stroke", function(d,i){
    return ( (d > data[i+1]) ?
             "red" : "black" )
    });
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/4xZwb/4/

Comment: And just for fussiness, the last fiddle with the y-axis the correct way up: http://fiddle.jshell.net/4xZwb/5/  Doh.

Comment: Great answer, @AmeliaBR.  Was wondering how you might approach this if a B-spline interpolation (aka curve) was required?  Since drawing individual line segments, it gets more complicated, right?  Or is there an easy way to do this?  e.g. see my slightly modified fiddle here with only 5 values: http://fiddle.jshell.net/4xZwb/36/

Comment: @ryanm If you need a curve, you'll need to use `<path>` not `<line>`. Probably easiest to use d3.svg.line to calculate the smooth curve (although you could do it yourself).  You'll need to pass the i-1, i, i+1 and i+2 data points so it can smooth things correctly, but then you will need to clip each path element to the i to i+1 interval, either by using a clip-path rectangle, or by going in and editing the path data returned by d3.svg.line.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at following three jsFiddles. The key idea of the solution is as @AmeliaBR said. Study thoroughly the link implementation in these three graphs (it's fairly simple). I extracted the most important parts of the code.

### [Red only](http://jsfiddle.net/VividD/9gAc9/)

```
.link_dashed {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #ff0000;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
    stroke-dasharray: 0,20,20,30,10,10,10;
}
```

[image]

### [Black only](http://jsfiddle.net/VividD/M7a34/)

```
.link_dashed {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000000;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
    stroke-dasharray: 20,20,30,10,10,10,0;
}
```

[image]

### [Red and Black](http://jsfiddle.net/VividD/LY46q/)

```
.link_dashed {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #ff0000;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
    stroke-dasharray: 0,20,20,30,10,10,10;
}
.link_dashed2 {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000000;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
    stroke-dasharray: 20,20,30,10,10,10,0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Well that certainly looks cool, although if I'm understanding the question correctly -- that the line between each point is supposed to be a colour based on the data -- then this won't achieve it without a lot of calculations to figure out the length of each line segment in the path.

Comment: Well, this is left as an exercise for the reader. :) @AmeliaBR

Comment: @AmeliaBR, we are complementary... Also, the question is fairly general.

Comment: The poster said "I have created an array of color that for which path what will be stroke color" so I assumed it is a constant. But even if its otherwise, it not hard to adjust the solution. :)