# How to delink datapoints so that we get two separate lines from the datapoints?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js, line

Consider the JSFIDDLE example http://jsfiddle.net/userla/5D5eD/2/ . In this example how to delink [4,4] and [5, 4] so that we get two separate linked lines

```
 [2,2],
[3,3],
[4,4],
[5, 4],
[5.5, 5],
[6, 6],
[6, 7],
[6.5,8],
[6.5,16],
[12,14],
[13,15],
[15,16],
[16,3],
[17, 16]
```

Comment: You could split it into two separate arrays.

Comment: var data = new array(); data[0] = [[2,2],
[3,3],
[4,4],
[5, 4],
[5.5, 5],
[6, 6],
[6, 7]];data[1]=[[6.5,8],
[6.5,16],
[12,14],
[13,15],
[15,16],
[16,3],
[17, 16]]; Is this correct ?

Comment: Well that depends where you want to split it. If you want to do that after `[4,4]`, that should be the last element of your first array.

Comment: But it is not showing any output. Should I add more code to the file ?

Comment: Yes. See e.g. [this tutorial](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/adding-more-than-one-line-to-graph-in.html).

Comment: The problem here is that your line is really a single svg:path element which can only have a single stroke color. So, you will need to change your code to draw individual lines which is more complicated. This [SO Question/Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219557/how-to-draw-different-color-path-between-center-and-different-nodes-in-d3-js) has all the details by @AmeliaBR. If this is too complicated, there might be other examples that are simpler. Do some googling now that you know what the issues are.