# D3 line .defined() with different array

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Link to ObserveableHQ: https://observablehq.com/@kickout/rectangles

I've looked at these sources [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791251/path-transition-with-gap-how-do-to-that), [here](https://bocoup.com/blog/showing-missing-data-in-line-charts)

Problem I am trying to solve: I draw 3 separate paths on a nested data object (each a different color). Those paths are drawn based on (x,y) data. I want to have a the lines break when a different array (z) doesn't match (d.chr in my case)

Line chart portion:

```
ndat1.forEach(function(d) {
    svg.append("path")
    .attr('fill','none')
    .attr("class",d.name)
    .attr("stroke",colors(d.name))
    .attr("d", line(d.effects))
    .attr('opacity',0.1)
    })
```

Line function (works fine without defined snippet):

```
line = d3.line()
  //.defined(d => ndat1[d.chr]==1)
  .x((d, i) => xScale(i))
  .y(d => yScale(d))
```

Do i pass the entire `d` to the line function (haven't got that to work) so that I can access both the y array (`d.effects`) and the defined array (`d.chr`)? I basically want to use a different array for `d3.line().defined()` than i do for `d3.line().y()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`d3.line().defined` just needs an array with true/values or `null` so there are a couple options:

1) Calculate and array with the length of the array you pass to `d3.line()`, ala: 
`breaks =  dat.map(d => d.chr).map((d,i) => ndat1[0].chr[i-1] != ndat1[0].chr[i] && i>0 ? true : null)`

2)Option 1 will work, but i think it will exclude points that already have data, so I spliced in some null values, and just copied every other approach (`.defined(d => !isNaN(d.value))`:

```
breaks =  dat.map(d => d.chr).map((d,i) => ndat1[0].chr[i-1] != ndat1[0].chr[i] && i>0 ? i : null)
br1=breaks.filter(d => d != null)
d3.range(4).forEach((d,i) => dat.splice(br1[i],0,{'chr':null,'pos':null}))
```